# Model Association for sharing a note with user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

User U1 shares a note N1 with user U2 and user U2 shares note with user U3.
When user U1 removes user U2 from note N1, then user U3 should also not able to see the note.How to implement this? 
 What will be my  model look like
Thank you in advance 
This is how my tables look like:-

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170909050804) do

  create_table "note_permissions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "note_id",       null: false
    t.integer "student_id",    null: false
    t.integer "granted_by_id"
    t.index ["granted_by_id"], name: "index_note_permissions_on_granted_by_id"
    t.index ["note_id", "student_id", "granted_by_id"], name: "my_index", unique: true
    t.index ["note_id"], name: "index_note_permissions_on_note_id"
    t.index ["student_id"], name: "index_note_permissions_on_student_id"
  end

  create_table "notes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "body"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "students", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "rollnumber"
    t.string   "subject"
    t.string   "room_no"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end    
end
```

This is my model

```
class Note < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :note_permissions  
end

class NotePermission < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :note
  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :granted_by, class_name: "NotePermission", dependent: :destroy
end

class Student < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :note_permissions
  has_many :notes, through: :note_permissions
end
```

Comment: To clarify... If U1 --> U2 --> U3 --> U4, and U2 unshared with U3, then is U4 now unable to view the note? This was my interpretation of the question, but perhaps that's not actually what you want.

Comment: @TomLord what u said is absolutely correct . Should i use ancestry gem for this type of association.

Answer (score 0):

So you have like a permission tree there, starting with `U1` granting access permission `U2` on their (`U1`) authority, and `U2` granting to `U3` in turn.

This could work by having a single root permission for a note, (for `U1`) and then all other permissions are granted by another permission using a foreign key

Something like:

```
create_table :notes do |t|
  # fields
end
create_table :note_permissions do |t|
  t.belongs_to :note,       null: false, foreign_key: true, on_delete: :cascade
  t.belongs_to :user,       null: false, foreign_key: true, on_delete: :cascade
  t.belongs_to :granted_by, null: true
  t.foreign_key :note_permissions, column: :granted_by_id, on_delete: :cascade
  t.index [:note_id, :user_id, :granted_by_id], unique: true
end

class Note < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :note_permissions
end
class NotePermission < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :note
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :granted_by, class_name: "NotePermission", dependent: :destroy
end
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :note_permissions
  has_many :notes, through: :note_permissions
end
```

Now when a user creates a note, also create a matching `NotePermission` (`granted_by: nil`, so the root).

```
# Plus other fields you want, like its contents
# Create a note with user_1
note = Note.create(note_permissions: [NotePermission.new(user: user_1)])
```

Will do something like:

```
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO "notes" DEFAULT VALUES RETURNING "id"
  INSERT INTO "note_permissions" ("note_id", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id"  [["note_id", 2], ["user_id", 1]]
COMMIT
```

Any user with a `NotePermission` recording matching their user ID and the note has access, and when they grant someone else permission, use their `NotePermission` record as the `granted_by`.

```
user_1.notes.find 1 # note
user_2.notes.find 1 # ActiveRecordNotFound

# user_1 grants user_2 permission
NotePermission.create!(note: note, user: user_2, granted_by: user_1.note_permissions.find_by(note: note))
# user_2 can now see
user_2.notes.find 1 # note
# user_2 grants user_3 permission
NotePermission.create!(note: note, user: user_3, granted_by: user_2.note_permissions.find_by(note: note))
```

You may want disallow people being granted permission twice (change the unique constraint), e.g. `U1 -> U2 -> U4` and `U1 -> U3 -> U4`), or you need to handle the multiple paths when `U4` grants `U5` (because you now have `U1 -> U2 -> U4 -> U5` AND `U1 -> U3 -> U4 -> U5`).

When you delete a `NotePermission`, you will invalidate anything they granted via that `granted_by`.

```
# Now have 3 permissions
NotePermission.all
NotePermission id: 1, note_id: 1, user_id: 1, granted_by_id: nil
NotePermission id: 2, note_id: 1, user_id: 2, granted_by_id: 1
NotePermission id: 3, note_id: 1, user_id: 3, granted_by_id: 2

# user_1 removes user_2
NotePermission.where(note: note, user_id: 2, granted_by: user_1.note_permissions.find_by(note: note)).delete_all
# Executes `DELETE FROM "note_permissions" WHERE "note_permissions"."note_id" = 1 AND "note_permissions"."user_id" = 1 AND "note_permissions"."granted_by_id" = 1`
# Because of the cascade, now have
NotePermission.all
NotePermission id: 1, note_id: 1, user_id: 1, granted_by_id: nil

# So the deletion of record 2, also caused the deletion of record 3 because of the granted_by_id foreign key
```

Comment: Sorry, sir i can't get you "Now when a user creates a note, also create a matching NotePermission (granted_by: nil, so the root)......." for the first time when a user create a record note permission column will be nil then when he grant permission for two user for eg(u2 and u3) i will insert another record in note_permission or i need to update the same existing record in note permission

Comment: I didn't put a permission column on, the note, see the `create_table`, but rather have Rails create both a `Note` and a `NotePermission` record at the same time.

Comment: first i created a student s=Student.create(name: "John") and then a note n=Note.create(body: "First note") and then i did as u said note = Note.create(note_permissions: [NotePermission.new(user: user_1)]) it giving me error as granted_by cannot be null

Comment: Not sure why you made 2 `Note`s, they will be different notes. Make sure you didn't set `null: false` for it in the table. Also if your using Rails 5 (although you tagged Rails 4), there is an API change, and you need `optional: true` on the `granted_by` in the `NotePermission` class